# Default prompt for date using month names from month numbers in OBIEE 11G analysis

Tags: sql, date, oracle11g, prompt, obiee

Our database has a field for months as periods 1,2,3, . . . and a field for years. I would like the prompt to have month names instead of digits and I would like to have a prompt for my analysis that defaults the prior month from the time the report was run. I have year and month working in digit format(works for every month except if run in January) but I can't seem to get a solution that works with month names defaulting to the prior month.

The months need to be Year to Date, so <= the prior month.

I am in accounting so it is to get the ledger for the last day of the prior month. Each period month has just the activity for that month, so Prior year is 0, Current year activity is <>0 and the balance as of the month is 0 through the prior month.

I want users to be able to change the selections if they need but have defaults selected that they will use 99% of the time.

Right now, with the period numbers I was using

```
SELECT "Date"."Fiscal Period Nbr" 
FROM "General Ledger" 
WHERE "Date"."Fiscal Period Nbr" = (VALUEOF(Current_Month) - 1)
```

And for the years

```
SELECT "Date"."Fiscal Yr Nbr" FROM "General Ledger"
WHERE "Date"."Fiscal Yr Nbr" = (VALUEOF(Current_Year))
```

I created a group for each month selecting the periods, so January is 0,1 and February is 0,1,2 and so on. In the prompt I select those 12 groups and was trying to do some sort of SQL for the Default selection.

Comment: Do you have the ability to edit the RPD to add a RPD variable that can always store the prior month? You said you were in accounting so I wasn't sure.

Comment: I don't, I am in the techy accounting guy that wants to make our reports better and easier. I am pretty new at OBIEE but I may be able to request that from IT. Thanks

Comment: For the previous month question, I can almost guarantee there is a repository variable named `PREVIOUS_YEAR`. You would use it similar to how you used 'CURRENT_YEAR` up in your  `WHERE` clause. If not, from a scalability standpoint, I would request such a variable from your BI team.

Comment: Previous_Month didn't work so I think that I would request that variable, thank you!